# Every perfect cube is the difference of two perfect squares?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How would you prove this without induction? I know that one easy way is using Al Kharchi's principle (namely that $1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3=(1+2+3+...+n)^2$), but are there other ways? Thanks!

Comment: what is the source of the name "Al Kharchi's principle"?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It's in my old pre-calc book. Would you like me to upload a picture with the proof? (it's a diagram)

Comment: no no, you don't have to. Actually, I have never heard this

Comment: Yes I figured that it's very obscure and that's why I explicitly showed it in my question, and I think it's really nice and potentially very useful to some people.

Comment: I heard this nice fact earlier, but not by the name. Have you noticed the generalization and the comment by  André Nicolas

Comment: I just read your answer, thank you for the generalization

Comment: @labbhattacharjee A [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number#History) mentions several mathematicians known to have studied this identity. One of them ***Al-Karaji*** whose name can also be spelled in other ways in the Latin alphabet.

Comment: Actually, there seems to be doubt over what the real (native) name of al-Karajī (or al-Karkhī) was, i.e. which birth location he got his name from. Source: His biography on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $a^2-b^2=n^3=n^2\cdot n$

we can set $a+b= n^2$ and $a-b=n$

so that $a=\frac{n^2+n}2=\frac{n(n+1)}2$ which is an integer as $n(n+1)$ is even

Similarly, $b=\frac{n^2-n}2=\frac{n(n-1)}2$

More generally, if $a^2-b^2=n^{k+1}=n^k\cdot n$ for integer $k\ge2$

we can set $a+b= n^k$ and $a-b=n$  so that $a=\frac{n^k+n}2=\frac{n(n^{k-1}+1)}2$

Observe that $n$ and $n^{k-1}+1$ have opposite parities, making the product even

Similarly,  $b$ can be handled

Comment: Should add that $n^2, n$ have the same parity, hence $a, b$ will be integers.

Comment: @CalvinLin, I was going to add that

Comment: @ovi: Note that a very similar argument shows that any odd number, and any number divisible by $4$, is a difference of squares.

Comment: You can simply say that since $a+b=n^{k-1}$ and $a-b=n$ have the same parity,  hence $a = \frac{ (a+b)+(a-b)} {2} $ will be an integer. This works for all powers (in part, since either $n$ or $n^k+1$ will be even).

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks, I'll try to prove it on my own

Answer (score 10):

Of course, explicitly saying what you have,

$$ n^3 = \left( \frac{ n (n+1) } { 2} \right ) ^2 - \left( \frac{ n (n-1) } { 2} \right ) ^2 $$

Comment: I think we should show how it is derived

Comment: It was derived as explicitly writing out what OP had, namely that $1 + 2 + \ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. And then it can be checked through algebraic expansion. I like your factorization better though.

Comment: but is this method susceptible to generalization like the one I've used?

Comment: Nope, and that wasn't the question. Of course the generalization to higher powers would allow for many different answers, as indicated by your factorization. $n^k = n \times n^{k-1} = n^2 \times n^{k-2} $ etc will all lead to different squares.

Comment: @Calvin Lin: thanks, but I was looking for a proof that does not come from Al Kharchi's principle.